# Poor performance Arrow Parquet multiple files

Tags: r, parquet, apache-arrow

After watching the mind-blowing webinar at Rstudio conference [here](https://rstudio.com/resources/rstudioglobal-2021/bigger-data-with-ease-using-apache-arrow/)  I was pumped enough to dump an entire SQL server table to parquet files. The result was 2886 files, (78 entities over 37 months) with around 700 millons rows in total.
[image]

Doing a basic select returned all rows in less than 15 seconds! (Just out of this world result!!)  At the webinar Neal Richardson from Ursa Labs was showcasing the Ny-Taxi dataset with 2 billions rows under 4 seconds.

I felt it was time to do something more daring like basic mean, sd, mode over a year worth of data, but that took a minute per month, so I was sitting 12.4 minutes waiting for a reply from R.

[image]

What is the issue? My badly written R-query? or simply too many files or granularity (decimal values?)??

Any ideas??

PS: I did not want to put a Jira-case in apache-arrow board as I see google search does not retrieve answers from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess (without actually looking at the data or profiling the query) is two things:

1. You're right, the decimal type is going to require some work in converting to an R type because R doesn't have a decimal type, so that will be slower than just reading in an int32 or float64 type.
2. You're still reading in ~350 million rows of data to your R session, and that's going to take some time. In the example query on the arrow package vignette, more data is filtered out (and the filtering is very fast).

Comment: Hi Neal, just a follow up here, thanks to your efforts and of the entire team, the same code -now running under Arrow 6.0- took only 2,7 minutes. 
Our 1500DW Azure SQL instance, runs the same i 53 seconds,  that cost around USD 4200 per month and in all fairness i have only  3% performance access to that, but still is mind-blowing, that a single user can run this level of complexity in a laptop, locally. Thanks Neal!